# How to verify if method was called from other by mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am trying to mock the behavior of a method that is called inside another so that it simulates the return of an object and another time it raises an exception but not if exactly if it is possible and if it is how it would be possible.

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class CategoryService {

    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepository repository;

    public Category findById(Integer id) {
        Optional<Category> obj = repository.findById(id);
        return obj.orElseThrow(() -> new ObjectNotFoundException(id.toString()));
    }


    public Category update(Category category){
        // Throws ObjectNotFoundException if not found before update
        this.findById(category.getId());
        return repository.save(category);
    }

}


@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CategoryServiceUnitTest {

    @Mock
    private CategoryService service;

    @Test()
    public void Should_UpdateCategory_When_FindCategory() {
        Category cat = new Category(1, "Test");
        //Is it possible?
        when(service.findById(Mockito.anyInt())).thenReturn(cat);

        Category category = service.update(cat);
        assertThat(category.getName()).isEqualTo(cat.getName());

        verify(service, times(1)).update(cat);
    }

    @Test(expected = ObjectNotFoundException.class)
    public void Should_ThrowsObjectNotFoundException_When_NotFoudCategoryById() {
        Category cat = new Category(1, "Test");
        //Is it possible?
        when(service.findById(Mockito.anyInt())).thenThrow(ObjectNotFoundException.class);

        service.update(cat);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the point of testing CategoryService by mocking it?

Comment: @htn imho is to ensure that the findById () method will be called to prevent it from attempting to update a record that does not exist and throw an exception. This way if someone accidentally remove this call will give an error in the test.

Comment: Probably you don't want to mock the _CategoryService_ as @htn mentioned. Maybe try to mock _CategoryRepository_ and create _CategoryService_ with that mock. So you can test the _CategoryService_ and also verify its behaviour with the mock.

Comment: Its not clear to me yet! Why not mock `CategoryService` in this case to call the `findById()` from it?

Comment: Because there is no point to mock what you just like to test. So here you want to test the methods of the `CategoryService`. If you mock it you don't test it.
Usually you mock the dependencies (here `CategoryRepository`) what you about to test.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, what you want to do is mock `CategoryRepository` in your test.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CategoryServiceTest {

    private CategoryService service;

    @Mock
    private CategoryRepository repository;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        service = spy(new CategoryService(repository));
    }

    @Test
    public void Should_UpdateCategory_When_FindCategory() throws ObjectNotFoundException {
        Category cat = new Category(1, "Test");

        when(repository.findById(Mockito.anyLong())).thenReturn(Optional.of(cat));
        //return the category object that is used to call the repository.save(...) method
        when(repository.save(Mockito.any(Category.class)))
                .thenAnswer((Answer<Category>) invocation -> {
                            Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
                            return (Category) args[0];
                        }
                );
        //depending on your requirements the above might be overkill, just replace that logic with this
        //when(repository.save(Mockito.any(Category.class))).thenReturn(cat);

        Category category = service.update(cat);

        assertThat(category).isNotNull();
        assertThat(category.getName()).isEqualTo(cat.getName());

        verify(service).update(cat);
    }

    @Test(expected = ObjectNotFoundException.class)
    public void Should_ThrowsObjectNotFoundException_When_NotFoudCategoryById() throws ObjectNotFoundException {
        Category cat = new Category(1, "Test");

        when(service.findById(Mockito.anyLong())).thenThrow(ObjectNotFoundException.class);

        service.update(cat);
    }
}
```

You'll also need to handle the checked exception `ObjectNotFoundException`. I just added the exception to the method signature, you might want to handle it differently in a production setting

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class CategoryService {

    private final CategoryRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public CategoryService(CategoryRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public Category findById(Long id) throws ObjectNotFoundException {
        Optional<Category> obj = repository.findById(id);
        return obj.orElseThrow(() -> new ObjectNotFoundException(id.toString()));
    }

    public Category update(Category category) throws ObjectNotFoundException {
        // Throws ObjectNotFoundException if not found before update
        this.findById(category.getId());
        return repository.save(category);
    }
}
```